# Display window full screen on secondary monitor using Qt

Tags: qt

Seems to be possible with native controls (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401240/display-os-x-window-full-screen-on-secondary-monitor-using-cocoa) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753552/going-fullscreen-on-secondary-monitor)) so now I'm looking for some Qt code to do it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use this code for the second display in full screen successfully on both Windows & Linux

```
QRect screenres = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(1/*screenNumber*/);
SecondDisplay secondDisplay = new SecondDisplay(); // Use your QWidget
secondDisplay->move(QPoint(screenres.x(), screenres.y()));
secondDisplay->resize(screenres.width(), screenres.height());
secondDisplay->showFullScreen();
```

Comment: This doesn't work longer in Qt5. QWidget is shown on the first screen.

Comment: Confirmed not working on Qt5. Moving window after setting fullscreen appears to work.

Comment: I think problem with this code is that screen sizes may vary so just dividing full resolution with screencount is a gamble that may work depending on your screen resolutions.

Answer (score 20):

One way of doing it in Qt5 is to use `QWindow::setScreen` to set the screen on which the window should be shown. `QWidget` has a `windowHandle()` that returns the pointer to the `QWindow`.

Here is how to show your widget on second screen in full-screen mode :

```
QWidget * widget = new QWidget();
widget->show();
widget->windowHandle()->setScreen(qApp->screens()[1]);
widget->showFullScreen();
```

Answer (score 6):

My take on this:

```
  auto const desktop(QApplication::desktop());

  setGeometry(desktop->screenGeometry(1));

#ifndef Q_OS_WIN
  setWindowState(Qt::WindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen | windowState()));
#endif // Q_OS_WIN
```

Answer (score 5):

showFullScreen first, then setGeometry.

Qt5 tested OK

Comment: Would you mind including a code sample? It would make your answer more valuable.

Comment: This actually does not work, WindowState is reverted to NoState when you call setGeometry.

Answer (score -1):

This problem got solved while using window->showFullScreen() instead of window->show().