# Qt screen names?

Tags: c++, qt

I've found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203095/display-window-full-screen-on-secondary-monitor-using-qt). But lets say I have three monitors, how can I distinguish between them? Can I get the screen name (e.g. Samsung) somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

From what I know, Qt only [provides functionality](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qdesktopwidget.html) to determine how many screens are available, what the index of the primary screen is, and what the geometry for a particular screen is.

Assuming you're working under Windows:

You could try to see if the IDs assigned, match those that the OS assigns in your multi-monitor configuration.
If you want to go more low level than that, you might want to have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181064/enumdisplaydevices-vs-wmi-win32-desktopmonitor-how-to-detect-active-monitors) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Qt5 has [`QGuiApplication::screens(i)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screens) with [`QScreen::name()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#name-prop) and (from 5.9 on) even [`::model()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#model-prop).