# Creating NSWindow in fullscreen mode

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, osx-lion

Is there a way to create a NSWindow into fullscreen mode? NSWindow has the ToggleFullscreen: selector but then it creates the window normally and animates it to the fullscreen version which isn't what I want. Any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 4):

First find the screen size

```
    NSRect screenRect;
    NSArray *screenArray = [NSScreen screens];
    unsigned screenCount = [screenArray count];
    unsigned index  = 0;

    for (index; index < screenCount; index++)
    {
        NSScreen *screen = [screenArray objectAtIndex: index];
        screenRect = [screen visibleFrame];
    }
```

`screenRect` contain Screen size, now creat a window and set `NSWindow` size to screen size.

```
unsigned int styleMask = NSTitledWindowMask 
                           | NSMiniaturizableWindowMask;


  myWindow = [NSWindow alloc];
  myWindow = [myWindow initWithContentRect: screenRect
                       styleMask: styleMask
                       backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered
                       defer: NO];
  [myWindow setTitle: @"This is a test window"];
```

Comment: Doesn't this just maximised the window, not put it into Fullscreen mode?

Comment: Refer http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000028.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401240/display-os-x-window-full-screen-on-secondary-monitor-using-cocoa

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

    NSRect frame=[NSScreen mainScreen].frame ;
    [self.window setFrame:frame display:YES animate:YES];
}
```

this will open window in full screen

Comment: Great, but how to set-up an app to launch into full-screen using storyboards?