# Unsupported Configuration Error in Cocoa (Xcode )

Tags: cocoa, window, warnings, fullscreen, nsview

I need a full screen window with a lot of stuff in it , made by Cocoa Xcode 4. But there is a persistent warning: any time I try to resize the main window, I receive this warning ( code compiles well , but I am sure something will go wrong for users with small screens)
this is the warning:

> **" Unsupported Configuration
>       Content rectangle not entirely on screen with the menu bar ( May not be completely seen for all screen resolution and
>   configurations)"**

I have 2 questions:

1- what is best way to get rid of this warning (except using smaller window because the warning starts around 560 x 560 window size. I can't use such a small screen for that stuff)

2- How can I tell the program to open in full screen at the beginning ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You just need to move the window in the sizing inspector in IB.
2. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338314/creating-nswindow-in-fullscreen-mode) should answer that.

Comment: Thanks. I checked that link and found instead of using the whole initWithContentRect method, I can use a simpler way.  By how, your answer led to my solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I could use under this link that thankfully "trojanfoe" let me know

[Creating NSWindow in fullscreen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338314/creating-nswindow-in-fullscreen-mode)

This is simplified code:

> Remember that Cocoa does not make @synthesize in AppDelegate.m for
>   default window. You need to add @synthesize window; manually

1- first we fill up screenRect with screen size
2- in size inspector set window position to " Fixed from Left" and make any offset needed you must payoff that offset in your code later ( Here I used 10 px of offset and 40px pay off. this resulted in exactly the same window size as Xcode !
[image]

3- add this code:

> - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
>
>   // set to open in full screen mode:
>
>   NSRect screenRect;
>
>   NSSize screenSize;
>
>   NSArray *screenArray = [NSScreen screens];
>
>   NSUInteger screenCount = [screenArray count];
>
>   for (NSUInteger index=0; index < screenCount; index++)
>
>   {
>
>   ```
>   NSScreen *screen = [screenArray objectAtIndex: index];
>
>   screenRect = [screen visibleFrame];
>   ```
>
>   }
>
>   // Now screenRect contain Screen size
>
>   screenSize.height= screenRect.size.height;
>     screenSize.width= screenRect.size.width;
>
>   [window setContentSize:screenSize];
>      }

[image]