# Programmatically display a window in the secondary monitor in Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am writing a Cocoa application with multi monitor support. It has a window controller which loads a UI from a NIB file. I would like this window to appear on the secondary monitor rather than the primary one. Is it possible to achieve this programmatically ? Please note that it is not a full screen window, and the window does not have a menu bar.

Comment: I found this in 15 seconds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401240/display-os-x-window-full-screen-on-secondary-monitor-using-cocoa

Comment: Thanks. I saw this before. What i want to display is not a full screen window. I'll try to create the rect manually with the required coordinates and see whether it's working. But there should be a better way of doing this :)

Comment: Yes you'll need to use a different style mask and content rect, however it shows how to specify the screen the window should appear on.

Comment: Managed to get it working to a certain extent by calculating the new origin coordinates and using setFrameOrigin method of the window. However, this calculation becomes increasingly difficult if the user has a display alignment like [this](http://imgur.com/qGudTuG). What i want is to center the window in the secondary monitor in all cases. is it possible to achieve this programmatically ?